# WorkSpace Mechanics Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, formatting

I have been trying to install WorkSpace Mechanics for Eclipse but it is showing that

> No repository found at http://workspacemechanic.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/git.update/mechanic.

Did anyone got the same issue and resolved it?

Comment: There is a thread about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/workspacemechanic/VXDP4Yd2tsY). Sounds like the project is dead and you would need to build it from the source to use it.

Answer (score 5):

I've provided a new Update-Site:

https://alfsch.github.io/eclipse-updates/workspacemechanic

Build from sources from here:

https://github.com/alfsch/workspacemechanic

BR,

Alfred

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I fixed the "Install" link in the [eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/workspace-mechanic) so everything is working again. (The repo was moved to Alfred's github site as he already posted)